# Git clone --filter=blob:none throws errors over ssh but not over http(s)

Tags: git, ssh, https, gerrit, git-clone

When I try to clone a repo down from my gerrit instance using ssh I get a continous string of errors.

```bash
$ git clone --filter=blob:none "ssh://my-gerrit:29418/my-repo"
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
remote: Finding sources: 100% (262/262)
Receiving obremote: Total 262 (delta 71), reused 262 (delta 71)
Receiving objects: 100% (262/262), 30.23 KiB | 2.16 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (71/71), done.
fatal: remote error: want 58fb9aafcda4a7a4e82faf2edbbc09e4dc11a580 not valid
fatal: internal server error
fatal: remote error: want d1dbc63aca26b49cc110581cb173f4ba5ca4b0eb not valid
error: unable to read sha1 file of .gitignore (d1dbc63aca26b49cc110581cb173f4ba5ca4b0eb)
fatal: internal server error
fatal: remote error: want 9d4ecb53ac5a63682bdd5a59e9f7dc98841bca2b not valid
fatal: internal server error
error: unable to read sha1 file of README.md (9d4ecb53ac5a63682bdd5a59e9f7dc98841bca2b)
...
```

error repeats for every file...clone ends with

```
Updating files: 100% (76/76), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

If I do a git status to inspect what was checked out I see that all my files are marked as deleted and staged for commit...

```bash
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    README.md
```

If I `git restore --source=HEAD :/` as it states at the end of the clone it returns the same errors that were originally returned when I tried the clone originally.

```bash
$ git restore --source=HEAD :/
fatal: remote error: want d1dbc63aca26b49cc110581cb173f4ba5ca4b0eb not valid
fatal: internal server error
error: unable to read sha1 file of .gitignore (d1dbc63aca26b49cc110581cb173f4ba5ca4b0eb)
fatal: remote error: want 9d4ecb53ac5a63682bdd5a59e9f7dc98841bca2b not valid
error: unable to read sha1 file of README.md (9d4ecb53ac5a63682bdd5a59e9f7dc98841bca2b)
fatal: internal server error
```

However, if I try to do the same clone over https, it works.

```bash
$ git clone --filter=blob:none "https://my-gerrit:8443/a/my-repo"
Cloning into 'my-repo'...
info: detecting host provider for 'https://my-gerrit:8443/'...
info: detecting host provider for 'https://my-gerrit:8443/'...
remote: Finding sources: 100% (262/262)
Receiving objects:  4remote: Total 262 (delta 71), reused 262 (delta 71)
Receiving objects: 100% (262/262), 30.23 KiB | 2.01 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (71/71), done.
info: detecting host provider for 'https://my-gerrit:8443/'...
info: detecting host provider for 'https://my-gerrit:8443/'...
remote: Counting objects: 44, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (44/44)
remote: Total 44 (delta 1), reused 36 (delta 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (44/44), 97.76 KiB | 12.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
Updating files: 100% (46/46), done.
```

### Update

Also, coming over in my gerrit `error_log` is the following

```
[2022-07-07T08:42:00.278-04:00] [SSH git-upload-pack /my-repo (UserName)] ERROR com.google.gerrit.sshd.BaseCommand : Internal server error (user UserName account AccountNumber) during git-upload-pack '/my-repo'
org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPackInternalServerErrorException
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.upload(UploadPack.java:775)
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.commands.Upload.runImpl(Upload.java:101)
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand.service(AbstractGitCommand.java:109)
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.AbstractGitCommand$1.run(AbstractGitCommand.java:74)
        at com.google.gerrit.sshd.BaseCommand$TaskThunk.run(BaseCommand.java:491)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.logging.LoggingContextAwareRunnable.run(LoggingContextAwareRunnable.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.WorkQueue$Task.run(WorkQueue.java:612)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.WantNotValidException: want a9f652cfcd3c08e6b5911901259871226a319940 not valid
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack$AdvertisedRequestValidator.checkWants(UploadPack.java:1856)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.parseWants(UploadPack.java:1807)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.processHaveLines(UploadPack.java:1696)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.fetchV2(UploadPack.java:1196)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.serveOneCommandV2(UploadPack.java:1294)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.serviceV2(UploadPack.java:1334)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.uploadWithExceptionPropagation(UploadPack.java:836)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UploadPack.upload(UploadPack.java:752)
        ... 12 more
```

It seems to print this for every sha associated with a file in the repo.

I prefer to keep cloning my repos down over ssh as I have a number of build jobs that clone the repos down over ssh. And if I can't get ssh to work I must update all my build jobs...

Is this an ssh setting or something that I can fix on my gerrit instance? Or is it something client related?

Comment: It seems likely that when using ssh, you're getting a different Git version than when using https. Otherwise they should behave the same way: both operating smoothly, or both producing these internal errors. The internal errors imply that the version of ssh you're getting when using ssh is defective (probably should be upgraded).

Comment: I'm finding `git version 2.33.1.windows.1` on my client, and `git version 2.34.1` on the gerrit server.

Comment: I'm also finding `OpenSSH 8.8` on my client, and `OpenSSH 7.4` on the gerrit server.

Comment: Are you using submodules in addition to filtered clones (promisor packs)? There were some fixes in 2.35 or 2.36 for this case. There's also a fix in 2.37 for something unrelated but it makes me wonder if the `info: detecting host provider for 'https://my-gerrit:8443/'...` lines are causing heartburn with submodules somehow.

Comment: No submodules at all.

Comment: @gh0st Still, try 2.37 from your Windows client, just to check if SSH would work better. Check also if you have any environment variable `GIT_SSH`(`_xxx`) set in your Windows CMD session.

Comment: @torek, if you know anything about gerrit, I've added what's printed out to the gerrit error_log while the clone is taking place.

Comment: @gh0st Is it a [protocol V1 vs. v2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e773545c7fe7eca21b134847f4fc2cbc9547fa14/Documentation/technical/protocol-v2.txt) issue? Would a `git -c protocol.version=1 clone ...` work?

Comment: @Vonc I'm coming to the realization that gerrit doesn't even use git. It uses jgit.

Comment: @gh0st Yes, which is why I would test, from the client side (non-gerrit, traditional Git), to use protocol v1.

Comment: @VonC, I don't think it's a protocol v1 vs v2 issue.  Using the `-c protocol.version=1` flag yeilds `error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 16d4be51ad19ca9b59fba2272ccfa13e9b14fde8` for every file.

Comment: Aha: the use of jgit potentially changes everything, since jgit and git are different programs, and `filter` is new enough that there may well be incompatibilities here. Try dispensing with the filtering entirely: probably everything will work fine. Obviously you want filtering for some reason (reduced network load?).

Comment: @torek, correct, without --filter everything works fine. Yes want filtering for the ability to clone down very large repositories with large artifacts much faster.

Comment: It may be impossible with your existing jgit servers: one of the changes from Git protocol V1 to V2 was to do away with the rule that allowed servers to deny arbitrary (well, apparently-arbitrary) raw hash IDs in "want" messages, and the reason for *that* was to make promisor packs work. Filtering is implemented via promisor packs.